# How to make Sinatra listen on two ports with socat

Tags: ruby, sinatra, socat

I had a classical Sinatra application which was accessible on two ports. After migrating it to modular style the second port is not working anymore.

My initial implementation was:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :port, 8080
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

----some routes-----
...
```

The resulting implementation was:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require_rel 'lib'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  register Sinatra::SomeRegister
  helpers Sinatra::SomeHelper

set :port, 8080
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

----some routes-----
...
run!
end
```

The application is run using:

```
socat tcp-l:8181,fork,reuseaddr tcp:localhost:8080 &
ruby /path/my_app.rb
```

The application doesn't respond on port 8181 anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to install socat first:

```
apt-get update && apt-get --allow-unauthenticated -y install socat
```